# grails application gmail smtp not working on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, grails, smtp

My gmail smtp in my grails application is working fine on windows but not working when it comes to ubuntu machine with same configuration. 
Configuration used by me are:

```
grails {
    mail {
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 465
        username = "*******@gmail.com"
        password = "*********"
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"false", "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
         "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false" ]
}
```

Comment: have you install Sendmail service on ubuntu machine ?.

Comment: use send mail action to send an email

Comment: def testAction() {
        sendMail {
            to "myfriend@gmail.com"
            subject "This is a test mail"
            body "Hello, This is a test mail, how are you?"
        }
    }

Comment: make "mail.smtp.auth":"true",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install and configure Sendmail on Ubuntu**

This should help you get Sendmail installed with basic configuration on Ubuntu.

If sendmail isn't installed,

1. install it:

   **sudo apt-get install sendmail**
2. Configure /etc/hosts file:

   **nano /etc/hosts**

3.Make sure the line looks like this:

**127.0.0.1 localhost yourhostname**

4.Run Sendmail's config and answer 'Y' to everything:

**sudo sendmailconfig**

5. Restart apache: 
   **sudo service apache2 restart.**

To check the status send of sendmail service

1: For start:
   **service sendmail start.**

2. For restart: 
   **service sendmail restart**

3.Check the status :
    **service sendmail status**

Comment: its active or deactive ?.

Comment: mail -s "Test Subject" <your email adress> if this command sends to your email then we can say that Sendmail service successfully else not install.

Comment: actually I'm working on grails(java) application. and "service sendmail status" showed "active and running"

Comment: using  <mail -s "test subject" ********@gmail.com> gives Cc: and then on entering it doesn't comes out of it.

Comment: on using echo "This is message body" | mail -s "This is Subject" someone@example.com             i received a msg in my spam but not working via application even on doin mail.smtp.auth : true

Comment: can update my point  if it helps for you so that it can refer by the people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The correct configuration is the following, I have used it without any instalations, on Ubuntu, MacOS and Windows:

```
grails {
 mail {
 host = "smtp.gmail.com"
 port = 465
 username = "your@email.es"
 password = "yourpassword"
 props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]

 }
}
```

Comment: but its not working on ubuntu even after using "mail.smtp.auth":"true"

Comment: Exception in sending email is:org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed;